# Sencha touch 2.0 can't set activeitem on viewport

Tags: javascript, web-applications, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I am playing with sencha touch 2.0 at the moment and i am having the following problem.

I am trying to set the activeitem on my viewport but according to my debug console the function is not being recognized. Yes my layout = card.

Can someone please tell me how i can change my view !

Here's my code

this is where it goed wrong :

//THIS IS WHERE IT GOES WRONG

```
                    App.view.Viewport.setActiveItem("App.view.user.Index",{
                        type: "slide",
                        direction: "left"
                    });
```

i also tried

```
this.App.view.Viewport.setActiveItem("App.view.user.Index",{
                        type: "slide",
                        direction: "left"
                    });
```

but that gives the same error: setActiveItem does not exist:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function () {
                    return this.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
                } has no method 'setActiveItem'
```

**The rest of the code if needed : App.js**

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig(
{ 
    enabled: true ,
    paths:{
        //set application path 
        App: 'app'
    }

});

// Main application entry point
Ext.application({
    name: 'App',  
        //Define all models and controllers in the application
        //Views do not have to be defined these are defined in the controllers

        //Models 

        //Controllers
        controllers: ['User'],
        //automatically create a viewport(template) instance/object  app/Viewport.js
        autoCreateViewport: true,
    launch: function() {              


    }
});
```

**Viewport**

```
Ext.define('App.view.Viewport', {
    extend: 'Ext.viewport.Default',
    xtype: "Viewport",


    config: {


        fullscreen:true,
        layout:     "card",
        items:[
            {
                xtype: "panel",
                scrollable:true,
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype:"toolbar",
                        title:"Test app"
                    },
                    {
                        xtype:"UserLoginView",
                        id: "LoginForm"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }

});
```

**Controller where everything is happening**

```
//Define controller name 
Ext.define('App.controller.User', {
    //Extend the controller class
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    views: ['user.Login','user.Index'],
    refs: [
        {
            selector:"#userLogin",
            ref: 'LoginUserLogin'
        },
        {
            selector:"#userPassword",
            ref: "LoginUserPassword"
        },
        {
            selector: "Viewport",
            ref: "Viewport"
        },
        {
            selector: "UserIndex",
            ref: "UserIndex"
        }
    ],
    //define associated views with this controller


    init: function()
    {
        //do something and setup listeners

        //setup listeners 
        this.control({
            '#UserLoginButon' : {
                tap : this.login

            }
        });
    },

    //handle
    login : function  (object)
    {
        //iniate loading screen for user
        var loadingScreen = new Ext.LoadMask(Ext.getBody(),{msg: ""});
        loadingScreen.show();


        //get form values 
        var username = this.getLoginUserLogin().getValue();
        var password = this.getLoginUserPassword().getValue();

        //check for empty fields
        if(username == "" || password == "")
        {
            loadingScreen.hide();
            Ext.Msg.alert("Foutmelding","Je dient alle velden in te vullen.");
        }
        else
        {
            Ext.Ajax.request(
            {
                url: '../backend/users/login/'+username+'/'+password,
                method: 'post',
                failure : function(response)
                {
                    loadingScreen.hide();
                    data = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
                    Ext.Msg.alert('Login Error', data.errorMessage, Ext.emptyFn);
                },
                success: function(response, opts) 
                {
                    data = Ext.decode(response.responseText);

                    if (data == true)
                    {
                        loadingScreen.hide();
                        Ext.Msg.alert("ingelogd!","welkom");

                        //THIS IS WHERE IT GOES WRONG 
                        App.view.Viewport.setActiveItem("App.view.user.Index",{
                            type: "slide",
                            direction: "left"
                        });




                    } else 
                    {
                        loadingScreen.hide();
                        Ext.Msg.alert("Foutmelding","Gebruikersnaam of wachtwoord klopt niet.");
                    }
                }
            });




        }
         console.log(App);









    },
    loginRequest : function (username, password)
    {

    }



});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According this post at the Sencha Forum http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?150668-ExtJS4-to-ST2 you shouldn't call Ext.Viewport directly in Sencha Touch 2, so I tried to create my own Viewport class and it worked, here's what I did:

app.js

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({enabled:true});
Ext.application({
        name: 'MyApp',
        controllers: ['MyController'],
        autoCreateViewport: true,
        launch: function() {
            console.log('launch!');
        }
    });
```

view/Viewport.js

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.Viewport', {
extend: 'Ext.Container',
xtype: 'my-viewport',
config: {
    layout: {
        type: 'card',
        animation: {
            type: 'slide',
            direction: 'left'
        }
    },
    fullscreen: true,
    items: [{xtype: 'my-list'}, {xtype: 'my-detail'}]
}
});
```

controller/MyController.js

```
Ext.define('MyApp.controller.MyController', {
extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
views: ['Navbar', 'List', 'Detail'],
init: function() {
    console.log('MyController init');

    this.control({
        'button[go]': {
                tap: function(btn) {
                    viewport = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('my-viewport');
                    target = Ext.ComponentQuery.query(btn.go);
                    viewport[0].setActiveItem(target[0]);
                }
            }
    });
}
});
```

This controller will basically look for any button with the "go" parameter and setActiveItem() to that value, so you just have to tell the button to go to the xtype of your view, like this:

```
{
    xtype: 'button',
    text: 'detail view!',
    go: 'my-detail',
    width: '20%'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't reference a panel by the class name, it's not referencing it's instance. Use your controller selectors or `Ext.ComponentQuery.query(selector)` (returns an array)

You could (should? I did) do something like this:

```
var indexPanel = Ext.create('App.view.user.Index');
Ext.Viewport.add(indexPanel)
Ext.Viewport.setActiveItem(indexPanel)
```

Comment: Great seems to do the job ! Is it possible though that I keep the toolbar that I have in my App.view.Viewport this dissapears.

Comment: You can either have a wrapping container containing two items, one being the toolbar (docked:'top') and the second being another container that you keep your "active" panel in. So you would reference that second item through a ref in your controller or componentQuery and destroy what's inside, add your new panel and set it as the active. I don't have any code samples of that exact functionality on me, but you can try playing with it.

Comment: isnt there a possibility to add the indexPanel to the already existing and created viewport easily? I would guess this is a pretty common proccess

Comment: Well that's what the code I gave you above does, adds it to the viewport. You can do that to any panel, just depends on how it's laid out. panel.add().. I think you may have to do panel.layout() or doLayout() after

Comment: i was talking about my own class that is extending the viewport ( sorry for the dumb questions i am kinda new to the javascript mvc and sencha system ) So what I i will do now is select the with the componentquery and then add my item and set an activeitem sound kinda inefficent though.

Comment: I think that's the way you have to do it. First instantiate it then you have to render it. Well you're 'supposed' to reference your custom viewport through the controller ref.

Comment: k, thanks ! Yh i already did it with some items i will do it like that than.

Comment: For everyone the answer to my question and my real question:
How do i use a already initiated component in my controller?

var loginView =  Ext.ComponentManager.get("Viewport"); This way you can use your viewport all the way you like to same goes for your views.